# CSS and HTML nav bar menu item

Tags: html, css

I having a problem getting menu items to reappear in CSS and html. The first two line of CSS code below, "display none", hides the menu items, in which I want.  However, the second code does not make the menu items appear again when the mouse is hovering over the menu. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
      ul li ul li ul li{
     display:none;
       }
     ul li ul li:hover {
     background: #696630;
     display:block; !important;
     }
```

Comment: Please include the html code and a snippet that we can try on

Comment: First of all you are you are not defining which element to be displayed in hover. Code would be helpful.

Comment: HTML is always handy for context, please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you want to reappear are the LI's nested further down, so ensure the hover is on the parent, but the element you actually style is the correct child.

```
ul li ul li ul li {
 display: none;
}

ul li ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see example below. In your code, you had `!important` behind the semicolon which is the wrong place. I should've been directly after block.

Don't use this when it can be avoided.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

li:hover {
  background: #696630;
}

.sub,
.subsub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: 0;
}

.main li:hover ul.sub {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub li:hover ul.subsub {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>Main
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Sub
        <ul class="subsub">
          <li>sub sub</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```